# development of webparts in sharepoint client

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

I am willing to learn "how to develop webparts using visual studio 2010" in client .

I had installed Sharepoint 2013 in windows server 2012 . But i want to develop the web parts in visual studio which is actually installed in my client machine.

I am using Visual Web developer 2010 and the OS is windows XP.

As I am a beginner in sharepoint, Can any one please help me,how to proceed on this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you [need at least the PRO version of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231582.aspx).

Secondly, only Vista and later are supported.

Then, you can work on your computer only for "sharepoint apps" that can deployed using the app model.

Most of time, it is far more preferable to work locally, directly on the server. Think about virtualization (I'm on W8 + hyper-v role, and autonomous sharepoint server + Visual studio as development environment).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I just want to know how can I develop web parts in Visual Studio 2010 which is not installed in Sharepoint server. I heard like if we add the Sharepoint API ISAPI in the Client then we can able to do this. But will you plz kindly help me how to do this out. Many Many Thanks. Cheers.